# Twitter Bootstrap Glyphicons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I believe I have the correct file path but I can still not get the glyphicons to appear. I have shared the link to the site and other info.

file path `../assets/img/glyphicons-halflings.png`

- assets contains css files & JS files
- I changed file path in given bootstrap css file to match (add assets).

here is the mark up

```
<h2 class="centeralign">
    <a class="large" href="mailto:t.grass@computer.org">
        <i class="icon-envelope"></i>Email Me: t.grass@computer.org
    </a>
</h2>
<h2 class="visible-phone centeralign">
    <a href="tel:4192330955">
        <i class="icon-phone"></i> 
        Call Me: 419.233.0955
    </a>
</h2>
<h2 class="hidden-phone centeralign">
    <i class="icon-phone"></i> Call Me: 419.233.0955
</h2>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ../assets/img/glyphicons-halflings.png *assets contains css files & JS files *

If the css file of bootstrap is in the `assets` folder, then you're directory traversing unnecessarily. Just remove `../assets/`.

```
img/glyphicons-halflings.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the default folder hierarchy often results in such issues. The fonts & bootstrap folder should be at the same level folder.
See another similar question:
[Bootstrap loading wrong glyphicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583025/bootstrap-loading-wrong-glyphicon)